# How to refactor common Gradle task configurations?

Tags: gradle

I have something like the following:

```
test {
    // bunch of common config stuff

    // some config stuff specific to `test`
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    // bunch of common config stuff

    // some config stuff specific to `integrationTest`
}
```

How can I avoid duplication of the 'bunch of common config stuff'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    // common stuff
}

test { ... }

task integrationTest(type: Test) { ... }
```

Comment: I see that you can also write "tasks.with(Closure)" if you want to select by something other than type.

Answer (score -1):

You can use methods: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html

```
test {
    config()
    // some config stuff specific to `test`
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    config()
    // some config stuff specific to `integrationTest`
}

void config() {
    // bunch of common config stuff
}
```

Comment: This won't work because the `config` method has a different scope. It can't access the properties available for a `Test` task.

Comment: How about config(this)? It could hit the proper scope. But I agree that @PeterNiederwieser's answer solves it better.

Comment: `this` isn't the same scope either. `config(delegate)` comes close.